# Issue with hovering over nav links

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the brass section of my navigation menu, I want to be able to hover over each item within and have a background color individually instead of all together. My problem is when I hover over the brass section that the entire block has a background color outright instead of going through one part at a time.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
body {
  background-color: #348899;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343642;
}
.wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #979C9C;
  color: #343642;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .sidebar h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li {
  padding: 15px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas {
  width: 25px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #B1B6B6;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Beginning Band Players - Home</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b698fbb6d0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>
        Navigation
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Brass</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="trumpet.html">Trumpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="frenchhorn.html">Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="trombone.html">Trombone</a></li>
            <li><a href="euphonium.html">Euphonium</a></li>
            <li><a href="tuba.html">Tuba</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Woodwind</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Percussion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Additional Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toolbox"></i>Maintenance</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your main issue was failing to close your `<li>` on the "Brass" line. I also noticed a few other minor errors in your formatting. HTML is very dependent on proper formatting, so please make sure you do this in the future. I would recommend using an widget on your IDE editor to allow auto formatting.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
body {
  background-color: #348899;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #343642;
}
.wrapper .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 160px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #979C9C;
  color: #343642;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .sidebar h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li {
  padding: 15px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas {
  width: 25px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #B1B6B6;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Beginning Band Players - Home</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b698fbb6d0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2>
        Navigation
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Brass</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="trumpet.html">Trumpet</a></li>
            <li><a href="frenchhorn.html">Horn</a></li>
            <li><a href="trombone.html">Trombone</a></li>
            <li><a href="euphonium.html">Euphonium</a></li>
            <li><a href="tuba.html">Tuba</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Woodwind</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Percussion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>Additional Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toolbox"></i>Maintenance</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your suggestion accomplishes some of what I'm trying to do. It resolves the issue of the background color being applied to everything within brass, but at the same time the pages within brass are also visible without hovering over brass

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, and you're going to want have to separate them into individual elements in order for each one to have their own hover effect. Separating them into their own hover effect starts with closing them off into individual `<ul>` and `<li>`

Comment: That would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set hover to your `anchor | a` element:

```css
.wrapper .sidebar ul li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .fas {
    width: 25px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover > a {
    background-color: #B1B6B6;
}
.wrapper .sidebar ul li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```